# Best way to automate file names of multiple databases

Tags: python, automation, fabric, devops

I have to SSH into 120 machines and make a dump of a table in databases and export this back on to my local machine every day, (same database structure for all 120 databases).

There isn't a field in the database that I can extract the name from to be able to identify which one it comes from, it's vital that it can be identified, as it's for data analysis.

I'm using the Python tool Fabric to automate the process and export the CSV on to my machine..

> fab -u PAI -H 10.0.0.35,10.0.0.XX,10.0.0.0.XX,10.0.0.XX -z 1
>   cmdrun:"cd /usr/local/mysql/bin && ./mysql -u root -p -e 'SELECT *
>   FROM dfs_va2.artikel_trigger;' >
>   /Users/admin/Documents/dbdump/dump.csv"
>   download:"/Users/johnc/Documents/Imports/dump.csv"

Above is what I've got working so far but clearly, they'll all be named "dump.csv" is there any awesome people out there can give me a good idea on how to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to modify your command as follow:

> mysql -uroot -p{your_password} -e 'SELECT * FROM dfs_va2.artikel_trigger;' > /Users/admin/Documents/dbdump/$(hostname)_dump.csv" download:"/Users/johnc/Documents/Imports/$(hostname)_dump.csv"

`hostname` returns current machine name so all your files should be unique (of course if machines have unique names)
Also you don't need to navigate to /bin/mysql every time, you can use simply `mysql` or absolute path `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql`

Comment: that hostname would have been an excellent approach.. unfortunately, the hostnames all have the same directory names due to the machines built for digital signage so they're set up exactly the same.

Comment: if they aren't VM you can try also `lsblk -dno serial /dev/sda`
this will return serial number of HDD, maybe not very informative but can be used as unique identifier

Comment: Because I'll be running the script locally it outputs it as my hostname not the remote machine which is a pain..

Comment: I could possibly install Fabric on all the machines and then run it from there as a daily cron, upload to my machine then create a bash script to rename all of the file names at once... although I'd of thought there would be a more simple way..

Comment: Does anyone have a better approach for this?